# Pgfplots legend of many columns, distribued column by column

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Here is a pgfplots code to plot three curves, with legend :

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf, tikz, pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[legend columns=2,]
    \addplot {x};
    \addlegendentry{$x$}
    \addplot {x+4};
    \addlegendentry{$x$+4}
    \addplot {-x+4};
    \addlegendentry{$-x$+4}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Here is the result, with the legend appearing over 2 columns :

[image]

The legend entries are displayed in the legend box line by line. I would like to display them column by column, like this (the linked picture has been manually set with gimp) :

[image]

Is there a way to do it ?

Comment: You could try `transpose legend`. Unrelated: `pgfplots` already loads `tikz` and `tikz` already loads `pgf`. So, there is no need to load all three packages.

Comment: yes indeed (once again I failed to type the right keyword to find this in the doc ).
Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a simple approach, you could make use of the option `transpose legend` which turns the columns into rows:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[legend columns=2, transpose legend]
    \addplot {x};
    \addlegendentry{$x$}
    \addplot {x+4};
    \addlegendentry{$x$+4}
    \addplot {-x+4};
    \addlegendentry{$-x$+4}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that using `transpose legend`, the option `legend columns` in fact takes the number of rows which you might want to adjust for longer legends:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[legend columns=3, transpose legend]
    \addplot {x};
    \addlegendentry{$x$}
    \addplot {x+4};
    \addlegendentry{$x$+4}
    \addplot {-x+4};
    \addlegendentry{$-x$+4}
    \addplot {-x+5};
    \addlegendentry{$-x$+5}
    \addplot {-x+6};
    \addlegendentry{$-x$+6}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Add the axis option 'axis equal' to show also the perpendicolarity of lines.